# How can I make is_page_template() workable in child theme?

Tags: templates

I am using a child theme. 
I want `no-sidebar.css` to be loaded if `page-nosidebar.php` is loaded. So I wrote the following code. It is not working. But it works in the Parent Theme:

```
function no_sidebar_style(){
    if (is_page_template('page-templates/page-nosidebar.php')) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'no-sidebar-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/no-sidebar.css');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'no_sidebar_style', 19);
```

If I write:

```
is_page_template(get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/page-templates/page-nosidebar.php')
```

instead of:

```
(is_page_template('page-templates/page-nosidebar.php')
```

as shown below, it still does not work:

```
function no_sidebar_style() {
    if (is_page_template(get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/page-templates/page-nosidebar.php')) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'no-sidebar-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/no-sidebar.css');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'no_sidebar_style', 19);
```

What do I need to do to make this code work?

Comment: Your first version of `no_sidebar_style()` looks fine.  Where did you place that code in your child theme? Can you elaborate on 'not working'? Are you getting a 404 on the stylesheet or is nothing happening at all? For debugging, you can use [`get_page_template()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template) to see the name of the template you're viewing.

Comment: Hello Dave, You are right, first version is fine. After your guideline. I have done my code with more attention. Now it is Okay. I am facing no trouble. But it was a trouble of 1 week. Many thanks.

Comment: Happy to help, Zulfikar. I've added my comment as an answer. Can you please accept it to help the next person that might run into this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first version of `no_sidebar_style()` looks fine:

```
function no_sidebar_style(){
    if (is_page_template('page-templates/page-nosidebar.php')) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'no-sidebar-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/no-sidebar.css');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'no_sidebar_style', 19);
```

For debugging, you can use [`get_page_template()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template) to see the name of the template you're viewing.